# Why does tooltip not work in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tooltip is not displaying. Only the title, which is usually displayed in a browser, is  showing...What can i do?

Here is my code.

Html code:

```
<form action="/validate.php" method="post" id="myform">
<table width="100%" border="1"><tr><td style="max-width:150px;">
<span id="l1" class="label">Username:</span></td><td 
    style="min-width:500px;"><input type="text" name="username" id="username" 

class="input" title="Username must contain only alphabets and numbers"/>
</td></tr><tr><td>
<span class="label" id="l2">Password:</span></td><td><input 

type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="input"/>
</td></tr><tr><td>
<span class="label" id="l3">Repeat password:</span></td><td><input 

type="password" name="rep-pass" id="rep-pass" class="input"/>
</td></tr></table>
</form>
```

Css:

```
.tooltip {
    background-color:#000;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    padding:10px 15px;
    width:200px;
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:12px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myform :input").tooltip({
position: "center right",
offset: [-2, 10],
effect: "fade",
opacity: 0.7
});
});
```

Comment: Tooltips were added new to jQuery UI version 1.9. What version are you using? Is it possible you have an earlier version? Just a guess.

Comment: @War10ck version 1.8.2 dont this work with this version

Comment: that is probably the version number of jQuery you are using. I'm using the same. (The latest is 1.8.3). In order to use tooltips though, you have to have at least version 1.9.0 of jQuery UI. The standard jQuery library does not have tooltips. Its the UI library that includes those. You can download it from [here](http://jqueryui.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your jQuery UI library. I could be wrong but your library that is version 1.8.2 should be your jQuery Library. jQuery UI has been above that number for quite a while. Even so, you must be running jQuery UI version 1.9.0 in order to use the new features such as menus, tooltips, etc.

[Download jQuery UI 1.9.0](http://jqueryui.com)

Answer (score -1):

As War10ck stated, this is not present in the version that you are using.  You choices would be to either update it, or use a different library.  I am a big fan of Twitter Bootstrap and the tooltips it offers, just my two cents :).